# extract columns from multiple text files with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract column1 based on the values of column2. I would like to print the values of column1 only if  column2 is ≤30 and greater than 5.

I also need to print the total number of the values of column1 based on the output. How can I do this with awk from multiple text files?

The sample of text file is shown below.

```
col1   col2  

aa     25
bb     4
cc     6
dd     23
aa     30
```

The output would be

```
aa
cc
dd
aa

Total number of aa is 2
Total number of cc is 1
Total number of dd is 1
```

Comment: As always, please post what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this to get you started:

```
{ if ($2 <= 30 && $2 > 5) {
    print $1
    tot[$1] += 1 }
}
END {

  for (i in tot) {
    print "Total number of", i, "is", tot[i]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f i.awk input
aa
cc
dd
aa
Total number of aa is 2
Total number of cc is 1
Total number of dd is 1
```

Comment: +1 - You can also do this: `$2 > 5 && $2 <= 30 {print $1; tot[$1]++}`. The changes are to put the lower bound to the left of the upper bound, use the conditional as a block selector instead of using an `if` and to use post-increment instead of `+=`.

Comment: Good feedback from one of my awk-heroes :-)